# How are ubuntu users using teamviewer?

Tags: xorg, wayland, teamviewer

Team viewer is only working on Xorg. Both of my friend run Linux, one of them runs ubuntu 18.04 and the other one runs Zorine, both can't run Team viewer on wayland.

I told them to switch to xorg whenever they want to use team viewer. Isn't there an alternative to that solution? They tried switching to AnyDesk and it caused many problems with the volume drivers and slider.

Isn't there any way to run Team viewer on Wayland?

Comment: It was my understanding that wayland is still very much so a toy with very little support for anything. While I'm not an expert by any stretch of the imagination, I wouldn't imagine there is support for teamview on Wayland. :(

Comment: @j-money but wayland is the default manager on all new distributions

Comment: well clearly I am an old fart then who needs to get with the times....

Comment: This is an excellent question for Teamviewer support. Wayland works with Ubuntu; that's our end of it. Bringing  Wayland compatibility to their proprietary application cannot be done by us on the outside.

Comment: Nope, wayland is not default manager anymore on 18.04 and 18.10.